Configure colour platette in chart widgets
I am using the cloud version of ThingsBoard.
I have a timeseries chart that shows all of the temperatures from multiple devices, from a 'Device search query' alias. I can select the colour for the first line on the graph, but cannot find a way to select the rest of the colour palette. Is there a way to do this, or edit the main colour palette used? I'd like to try and make all graphs either fully configurable, or follow a corporate theme.
Thanks.
I can find no options to set the colour palette.
